# How do i not display the first message in a string in if else statement validation

Tags: php

My code below checks if there are any fields that are not entered and then checks for validation the problem is when there are no errors it still displays the first error_message .=

E.g

```
$error_message .= "<div class=\"error-header\">Error: You did not submit the following required information.</div>";
    $error_message .= "<ul id=\"errors\">"
// this part in the second else statement always shows how do i stop that;
```

full code here:

```
if((!$email_address)||(!$password)||(!$confirm_password)||(!$first_name)||(!$last_name)||(!$address)||(!$postal_code)||(!$region)||(!$country)) {           
        $error_message .= "<div class=\"error-header\">Error: You did not submit the following required information.</div>";
        $error_message .= "<ul id=\"errors\">";
        if(!$email_address) {
            $error_message .= "<li>Please enter you're email address.</li>";
        }
        etc...
}else {
        $error_message .= "<div class=\"error-header\">Error: The following information is invalid.</div>";
        $error_message .= "<ul id=\"errors\">";

        if($row_count > 0) {
            $error_message .= "<li>The email address you provided is already in use, please use another email address.</li>";
        }

        if($confirm_password != $password) {
            $error_message .= "<li>The passwords do not match.</li>";   
        }

        if(!isset($_POST["interests"]) || count($_POST["interests"]) < 3) {
            $error_message .= "<li>Please choose three departments that are of interest to you.</li>";                              
        }else{
            $interests = $_POST["interests"];
        }

        if(strtolower($captcha_code) == strtolower((string)$_SESSION["captcha"])) {
            $error_message .= "<li>The code you entered is incorrect.</li>";    
        }

        $error_message .= "</ul>";
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified your code a bit:

```
if((!$email_address)||(!$password)||(!$confirm_password)||(!$first_name)||(!$last_name)||(!$address)||(!$postal_code)||(!$region)||(!$country)) {           
            $error_message .= "<div class=\"error-header\">Error: You did not submit the following required information.</div>";
            $error_message .= "<ul id=\"errors\">";
            if(!$email_address) {
                $error_message .= "<li>Please enter you're email address.</li>";
            }
            etc...
    }else {

            $error_message=""; 

            if($row_count > 0) {
                $error_message .= "<li>The email address you provided is already in use, please use another email address.</li>";
            }

            if($confirm_password != $password) {
                $error_message .= "<li>The passwords do not match.</li>";   
            }

            if(!isset($_POST["interests"]) || count($_POST["interests"]) < 3) {
                $error_message .= "<li>Please choose three departments that are of interest to you.</li>";                              
            }else{
                $interests = $_POST["interests"];
            }

            if(strtolower($captcha_code) == strtolower((string)$_SESSION["captcha"])) {
                $error_message .= "<li>The code you entered is incorrect.</li>";    
            }

             //check if there is any error message, then create the div
             if(!empty($error_message))
            {
               $errorMessageLi=$error_message;
               $error_message= "<div class=\"error-header\">Error: The following information is invalid.</div>";
              $error_message .= "<ul id=\"errors\">";

              $error_message .=  $errorMessageLi;

              $error_message .= "</ul>";
            }
         }
```

Comment: Why not just use $errorMessageLi throughout rather than swapping it at the end?

Comment: Yah.. I was feeling lazy :p

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like that's always executed.  You either need to control when `$error_message` is displayed (not shown here) or you need to put some check in that else block to see if you actually hit any of those if statements.

```
if (!($row_count = 0) && !($confirm_password != $password) && ...) {$error_message .= "";}
```

That would be a clunky way to do it; you could fairly easily check at the end to see if any `<li>` were added, and if not, clear it out; or else put a counter variable in and increment it in each if block (if true).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use arrays for such things:

```
$errors = array();

if (condition1) {
   $errors[] = 'condition 1 was not met';
}

if (condition2) {
  $errors[] = 'condition 2 was not met';
}
etc...

if (count($errors) > 0) {
   display error messages
}
```